# ASP.net: GridView trouble getting updated values

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using *GridView1_RowUpdating* event which is called after clicking "Update" link. In the method I handle updating of the GridView.
I want to get the values from textboxes (i.e. new values):

```
string title= ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
```

But strangely I get old value. I've debugged but couldn't find where the error is.

Also, e.NewValues.Count is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was doing GridView.DataBind() everytime in page_load. Solved now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind data to the gridView control